# Can we define a data type that can have multiple predefined values in excel-vba?

Tags: excel, vba

When we declare a variable/constant as Boolean, we get the option True/False while assigning it. Is it possible to define a data type in excel-vba that can hold multiple values just like Boolean data type? For example, a data type for an Octadecimal number that holds eight values.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. A good question explains the problem, things you tried (code!) and the problem you're stuck with and what you expected instead of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Type` or `Enum` statements to declare a custom type or enumeration.